# python Import requests error

Tags: software-installation, python, libraries, pip

So I keep getting this error everytime I try to run my python script.

```
import requests
ImportError: No module named requests
```

I have checked all the answers to this issue in other previous questions asked. I have done all the solutions, made sure it was python2.7, installed the requests. Yet every time I run it it still gives me that same error.

I have run

```
sudo install requests
```

and

```
easy_install -U requests
```

its all there, yet not functioning.

Is there something I am missing?

The only thing that seems off is I have 1 folder labeled `requests` and another labeled `requests-2.11.1-py2.7.egg` that both seem to have the same content inside them.

Comment: What distribution of Linux? Are you using its 'system' version of python, or have you installed a 3rd party version and/or created a virtualenv?

Comment: @steeldriver Darwin Kernel 16.0.0, I installed python using Xcode

Comment: Xcode and Homebrew

Answer (score 1):

So my issue was that I was using a cron, and the cron was specifying the script to use python version 2.7.10. And the script was trying to use version 2.7.12.

Specified crontab to use correct version, worked fine.